# How do I embed Android videoview as a custom plugin into phonegap/cordova app without it going full screen?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, icenium

I am developing a custom plugin for Cordova. At this point I am focusing on Android only and once I sort that part out I will move on to iOS.

I do understand the basics of Cordova 3.2 custom plugin development and integration and I have been able to get a few simple plugins running no problem. I am targeting Icenium but that really is only the host and Icenium is really just a wrapper around Cordova 3.2.

My issue is with controlling the interface.

By this I mean when I use some of the video plugins I found in github they invariably launch outside my own GUI. I had also taught myself how custom plugins work by using a calendar plugin for Android. This too took the user from my GUI into a full screen calendar page.

What I need to do is have the video plugin I wish to develop which will use the Android videoview integrate seamlessly with my own GUI.

So the video and moviecontroller would be visible right alongside other GUI elements in my hybrid mobile app. I can only find posts about people working with webviews and iframes and that is NOT what I am trying to do. I want the plugin to harness the native Android videoview/moviecontroller and seamlessly interact with my own GUI both visually and programmatically. I will need to pass events back and forth so anything that has me lose control of the GUI is unacceptable.

Thanks!!